# How to expand a div situated on top of another with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

I have a stack of div tags. Each div will contain hidden content. I want the hidden content to expand with the div that it is situated in when clicking on the view button at the bottom. When the div expands I want it to push all the content underneath it down. And if possible I would like it if by clicking on a different view button the previously expanded div will collapse. I am not very js competent but tried copying some simple code to start it off but couldn't get anything to expand.. please help!

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebenhafkamp/3vhpoL3t/

html

```
<div class="maincontent" id="main1">
  <img class="thumb" src="../images/main1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  <p class="text2"><h3>Lorem</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eros erat, dapibus sit amet pretium ut, pellentesque et leo.</p>
<h5>View</h5>
</div><!--maincontent-->
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/content-->
```

css

```
.maincontent{height:140px; width:900px; float:left;}
.content{display:none;}
```

js

```
$(".maincontent").click(function () {

$maincontent = $(this);
$content = $maincontent.next();
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    $maincontent.text(function () {
        return $maincontent.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change some of your html structure and css

**Changed html**

```
    <div class="maincontent" id="main1">
      <img class="thumb" src="../images/main1.jpg" width="100" height="100">
          <p class="text2"><h3>Lorem</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eros erat, dapibus sit amet pretium ut, pellentesque et leo.</p>
    <h5>View</h5>
<!--maincontent-->
        <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/content-->
    </div>
```

**Changed css**

```
.maincontent{
      width:900px;
      float:left;
}
.content{
  display:none;
  clear:both;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".maincontent h5").click(function () {
    $('.maincontent .content').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.content').slideDown();
});


});
```

Working **[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/3vhpoL3t/3/)**

Hope this works for you

Comment: You are a boss sir! :D Thank you so much! It's working great now :)

Comment: Just wondering, if your familiar with dw. I put the jQuery code into it's own .js file like so: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script> and made all the changes to the html and css but with no luck. For some reason the div won't expand. Heres a link to another text editor in which i can't get the code to work: http://codepen.io/Hafkamp/pen/jabmE

Comment: I think you haven't add jquery library http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: check it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGcxr I have added jquery library in html section

Comment: Magical. I was just reading into that but couldn't really wrap my head around it :P Thanks Sonasish!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without any changes to HTML code/structure, **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3vhpoL3t/4/)** here

```
$(".maincontent h5").click(function () {

    $maincontent = $(this).parent();
    $content = $maincontent.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500);
    $('.content').not($content).hide();
    $('.content').parent().not($maincontent).find('h5').html("View");

    var content=$(this).html();
    if(content=="View")                                    
    $(this).html("hide");
    else{
      $(this).html("View");  
    }
});
```

Hope this is helpful